# Meteor permission at field level (not Collection.allow )

Tags: meteor, user-permissions

*Collection.allow* provides a way to authorize or not the  insert/updated/delete of documents based, for instance, on user role.

However, here, I am looking for a generic solution to allow the read or write of, not a document, but a document's field, based on more precise roles.

Examples:

- Allow RoleA to see and edit item's price.
- Allow RoleB to only see item's price.
- Do not allow RoleC to see/edit item price, the client browser  would receive the item with all the fields except the price.

Another way to describe the example is using the following matrix:

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------+
| Schema Item | Field 'name'        | Field 'price' |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------+
+-------------+---------------------+---------------+
| Read        | RoleA, RoleB, RoleC | RoleA, RoleB  |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------+
| Write       | RoleA, RoleB, RoleC | Role A        |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

**How would you implement that matrix, or what solution would you pick to have a permission system that affects not documents, but fields ?**

Note: the question is asked as the application has around 15 document types, and between 10 and 20 user profiles, to avoid to have an insane 'if' complexity.

Regards

Comment: There is no such solution I can think of. I needed similar, but more general feature, and after unsuccessful search implemented it by myself. Probably you should do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the [alanning:roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) package. Then for reading I would implement the restrictions in your `publish` functions using something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('myPublication', function (group) {
  let fields = { name: 1};
  if ( !Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'RoleC',group) ) fields.price = 1;

  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['RoleA','RoleB','RoleC'], group)) {
    return MyPublication.find({},fields);
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

For writing I would probably go with [aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and enforce the role restrictions in an [autoValue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue) function.

I agree, however, that there isn't a generic solution where you create tables of permissions on a role x document x field basis. That would make for an interesting package.